# Aggregating data at 15 minutes interval based on date and hour in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse, aggregation

I have data as follows

```
Time <- c("2021-08-30 7:24","2021-08-30 7:30","2021-08-30 7:54","2021-08-30 8:16","2021-08-30 8:27","2021-08-30 8:22","2021-08-31 2:39","2021-08-31 2:44","2021-08-31 2:50","2021-08-31 2:56","2021-08-31 7:42","2021-08-31 7:45","2021-08-31 7:50","2021-08-31 6:02")
Distance_m <- c(162,162,162,162,162,162,162,157,150,137,122,102,78,42)
df <- data.frame(Time, Distance_m)
df
              Time Distance_m
1  2021-08-30 7:24        162
2  2021-08-30 7:30        162
3  2021-08-30 7:54        162
4  2021-08-30 8:16        162
5  2021-08-30 8:27        162
6  2021-08-30 8:22        162
7  2021-08-31 2:39        162
8  2021-08-31 2:44        157
9  2021-08-31 2:50        150
10 2021-08-31 2:56        137
11 2021-08-31 7:42        122
12 2021-08-31 7:45        102
13 2021-08-31 7:50         78
14 2021-08-31 6:02         42
```

I Want to sum the Distance_m based on 15 minutes intervals based on date and hour.

I am expecting the output as follows

```
Date    Hour    Time    Distance_m
2021-08-30  7   54  486
2021-08-30  8   30  486
2021-08-31  2   56  606
2021-08-31  6   2   344
```

So far I have tried

```
df <- tidyr::separate(df, Time, c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")
df1<- df %>%
  mutate(Time = hm(Time)) %>%
  mutate(ttt= (lubridate::minute(Time) + lubridate::hour(Time) * 60)) %>%
  mutate(tt = floor(ttt/15) ) %>%
  group_by(tt) %>%
  summarize(Date = last(Date),Time = last(Time), Distance_m = sum(Distance_m))
```

But the output is a bit messy. I am hoping to find an efficient way as I am dealing with a huge data.

Thank you

Comment: Can you briefly explain how the difference of 15 minutes is calculated? I could see 6 hour 2 mins in the fourth row which is the lowest among others on the same date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly giving your expected results though, but perhaps usable.
You can see if this fits your needs.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Time := ymd_hm(Time)]
df[, groups := lubridate::round_date(Time, "15 minutes")]
df[, .(Distance_m_sum = sum(Distance_m)), by = groups]

               groups Distance_m_sum
1: 2021-08-30 07:30:00            324
2: 2021-08-30 08:00:00            162
3: 2021-08-30 08:15:00            324
4: 2021-08-30 08:30:00            162
5: 2021-08-31 02:45:00            469
6: 2021-08-31 03:00:00            137
7: 2021-08-31 07:45:00            302
8: 2021-08-31 06:00:00             42
```

## More extended example

You have to define your quarters I think, there are with the lubridate approach three options, round_date, floor_date and ceiling_date. Rethinking my own example I would pick **floor_date** as 2021-08-30 7:24 falls in the 7:15-7:30 group. To see all variants:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Time := ymd_hm(Time)]
df[, round_date := lubridate::round_date(Time, "15 minutes")]
df[, floor_date := lubridate::floor_date(Time, "15 minutes")]
df[, ceiling_date := lubridate::ceiling_date(Time, "15 minutes")]

df[, .(Distance_m_sum = sum(Distance_m)), by = round_date]
            round_date Distance_m_sum
1: 2021-08-30 07:30:00            324
2: 2021-08-30 08:00:00            162
3: 2021-08-30 08:15:00            324
4: 2021-08-30 08:30:00            162
5: 2021-08-31 02:45:00            469
6: 2021-08-31 03:00:00            137
7: 2021-08-31 07:45:00            302
8: 2021-08-31 06:00:00             42

df[, .(Distance_m_sum = sum(Distance_m)), by = floor_date]
        floor_date Distance_m_sum
1: 2021-08-30 07:15:00            162
2: 2021-08-30 07:30:00            162
3: 2021-08-30 07:45:00            162
4: 2021-08-30 08:15:00            486
5: 2021-08-31 02:30:00            319
6: 2021-08-31 02:45:00            287
7: 2021-08-31 07:30:00            122
8: 2021-08-31 07:45:00            180
9: 2021-08-31 06:00:00             42

df[, .(Distance_m_sum = sum(Distance_m)), by = ceiling_date]
          ceiling_date Distance_m_sum
1: 2021-08-30 07:30:00            324
2: 2021-08-30 08:00:00            162
3: 2021-08-30 08:30:00            486
4: 2021-08-31 02:45:00            319
5: 2021-08-31 03:00:00            287
6: 2021-08-31 07:45:00            224
7: 2021-08-31 08:00:00             78
8: 2021-08-31 06:15:00             42
```

Comment: I believe that you should order the data and time before round_date.

Comment: There is no need to order any data and all three examples are correct, but just depending on how you want to define your 15 minute groups. Usually when you want to group timeline data you want to do that by the quarter, by the hour, by the day... Considering daily grouping I think most will agree that that includes all data points ranging between 00:00 and 23:59, for that same reason I prefer to use floor_date so that 7:24 becomes 7:15 (start of the quarter) and therefor between 7:15-7:30.

Comment: Floor_date worked perfectly for my case. However, I wanted to date, hour, and minutes separately in the final outcome because I need to plot the daily 15 minutes distance graphs, in which the x-axis should be minutes, y-axis should be distance grouped by each unique date. Any efficient way to do that in ggplot2?

Comment: I have tried this  "df <- tidyr::separate(df, floor_date, c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")
ggplot(df, aes(x=  Time , y = Distance_m_sum ,group = Date)) + geom_line(size=1) +
  facet_wrap(Date ~ .) +
  labs(title = "Daily Distance_m")"
But I'm having a problem adjusting the scale of the x-axis.

Comment: It is tricky, but there is a neat way without splitting the datetime into a date and a time. I made a new answer to get your plot done from A-Z.

Answer (score 1):

Base R option using `cut` to divide data in 15 minutes interval and `aggregate` to summarise the data.

```
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', tz = 'UTC')
aggregate(Distance_m~Time_cut, transform(df, Time_cut = cut(Time, '15 mins')), sum)

#             Time_cut Distance_m
#1 2021-08-30 07:24:00        324
#2 2021-08-30 07:54:00        162
#3 2021-08-30 08:09:00        324
#4 2021-08-30 08:24:00        162
#5 2021-08-31 02:39:00        469
#6 2021-08-31 02:54:00        137
#7 2021-08-31 05:54:00         42
#8 2021-08-31 07:39:00        302
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably wonder the 1900 part, this is because when facetting ggplot still has the whole dates in mind, so you do not get them stacked nicely by the hour. When facetting it is also hard to give a start and an end for limits as they fall in a different day. An alternative is splitting as you suggested in dates and hours but that makes you less flexible and lose your timeline imo.

```
Time <- c("2021-08-30 7:24","2021-08-30 7:30","2021-08-30 7:54","2021-08-30 8:16","2021-08-30 8:27","2021-08-30 8:22","2021-08-31 2:39","2021-08-31 2:44","2021-08-31 2:50","2021-08-31 2:56","2021-08-31 7:42","2021-08-31 7:45","2021-08-31 7:50","2021-08-31 6:02")
Distance_m <- c(162,162,162,162,162,162,162,157,150,137,122,102,78,42)
df <- data.frame(Time, Distance_m)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Time := ymd_hm(Time)]
df[, floor_date := lubridate::floor_date(Time, "15 minutes")]
df <- df[, .(Distance_m_sum = sum(Distance_m)), by = floor_date]

ggplot(df, aes(x= ymd_hms(paste("1900-01-01", str_sub(df$floor_date, 12))), y = Distance_m_sum, group = as.Date(floor_date))) + geom_line(size=1) + geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_wrap(as.Date(floor_date) ~ ., ncol = 1) + 
  labs(title = "Daily Distance_m") +
  expand_limits(x = c(ymd_h(1900010100), ymd_h(1900010200))) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "60 min", date_minor_breaks = "15 min", date_labels = "%H:%M", expand = c(0,0))
```

Comment: It saved a lot of my plotting time. Thank you.